# Hibernate session.update insert rows instead of updating rows

Tags: java, hibernate

Event.hbm.xml  one-to-many relationship for event to fights

```
<class name="Event" table="event">
  <id name="oid" type="long" column="oid">
  <generator class="increment">
     <param name="initial_value">1</param>
  </generator>
  </id>
<property name="address">
  <column name="address"/>
</property>
<property name="date">
   <column name="date"/>   
</property>
  <list name="fights" cascade="all">  
          <key column="eventOid"></key>  
          <index column="type"></index>  
          <one-to-many class="Fight"/>  
 </list>  
</class>
```

Retrieve existing Event

```
    public Event getEvtByDateAddress(String _date, String _address)
{
    try
    {
        if(!session.isOpen())
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Event.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("date", _date));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("address", _address));
        Event evt = (Event)criteria.uniqueResult();
        if (evt==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return evt;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The update is called.

```
    public int updateEvent(Event _event)
{
    try
    {
        if(!session.isOpen())
        {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        Event tmpEvent=new Event();
        if((tmpEvent=this.getEvtByDateAddress(_event.getDate(), _event.getAddress()))!=null)
        {
            tmpEvent.setFights(_event.getFights());
            Transaction tx =session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(tmpEvent);
            session.flush();
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return -254;
    }
}
```

After the update, results unexpected. New records are inserted instead of updated.

```
oid boxer1Oid   boxer2Oid   eventOid    type
  1         1           3         \N    \N
  2         2           4         \N    \N
  3         5           6         \N    \N
  4         7           8         \N    \N
  5         1           2          1    0
  6         3           4          1    1
  7         5           6          1    2
  8         7           8          1    3
```

Expected Result

```
oid boxer1Oid   boxer2Oid   eventOid    type
  1         1           2          1     0
  2         3           4          1     1
  3         5           6          1     2
  4         7           8          1     3
```

I simply retrieve the existing records and modify it, and it results unexpectedly.

```
if((tmpEvent=this.getEvtByDateAddress(_event.getDate(),_event.getAddress()))!=null)

            tmpEvent.setFights(_event.getFights());
            -------
            session.update(tmpEvent);
```

What am I missing to get the expected result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `this.getEvtByDateAddress` sets the `oid` of the entity returned by `getFights`.

Also, do not create a new event.  `Event tmpEvent=new Event();` can just be `Event tmpEvent = null;`

Comment: From the debugger, tmpEvent=this.getEvtByDateAddress, where the fights of tmpEvent is a PersistentList. Is it an expected result?

Comment: What are the oid values of the entities returned by getFights()?

Comment: _event.getFights() the oid of it  are all 0.

Comment: And that is your problem.  If the oid is 0, hibernate will insert instead of update.